# Bot framework web channel not accepting user attachments?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I created a Bot in microsoft azure and tried to test it here 
https://dev.botframework.com/ but the chat console is not accepting user attachments where as i tried to test in skype it is accepting and responding to user uploaded images, This issue is present only in webchat channel proivded by bot frame work 
--Please help if there is any need to change configurations of deployed BOT ?
Thanks In advance

Comment: What do you mean by "is not accepting user attachments"?

Comment: The issue got solved some how
-- I did'nt fix it  but started working from now